# MySQL A or B but NOT both

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, relation, self-join

This seems like an easy query but I cannot seem to get it or relate it to other posts on stack overflow. Would anyone be able to explain... This is what I have so far, it is returning records for all bars where one or both people go.

TBL frequents Schema - drinker VARCHAR(50) PK, bar VARCHAR(50) PK

Bars which are frequented by John or Rebecca but not by both of them

```
SELECT DISTINCT bar 
FROM frequents
WHERE drinker = 'John' XOR drinker = 'Rebecca' 
  AND bar NOT IN (
    SELECT f1.bar 
    FROM frequents f1, frequents f2
    WHERE (
      f1.drinker = 'John' 
      AND f2.drinker = 'Rebecca' 
      AND f1.bar = f2.bar
    )
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should satisfy the specification:

```
SELECT f.bar 
  FROM frequents f
 WHERE f.drinker IN ('John','Rebecca')
 GROUP 
    BY f.bar
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT f.drinker) < 2
```

---

- get all of `bar` for 'John' and/or 'Rebecca'
- collapse the rows to a single row for each `bar`
- get a count of `drinker` for each bar
- discard rows that have a count of 2 (i.e. both John and Rebecca)
- leaving only values of `bar` for John and not Rebecca or vice versa

Comment: I didn't know you can use the distinct keyword in count. That makes it much easier, thank you!